# Trigger not committing changes

Tags: apex, trigger

Im creating a trigger that when the record is inserted to the custom object, it will update the email in the contacts if it doesnt match the existing and also update a checkbox. but it doesnt seem to work. Although it catches the id of the contact, it doesnt update. Thanks

```
trigger updateEmpEmail on Public_Register_Employee__c (after insert, after update) {
    List <Public_Register_Employee__c> preNew = new List<Public_Register_Employee__c >();
    List <Public_Register_Employee__c> preNewQry = new List<Public_Register_Employee__c >();    
        for(Public_Register_Employee__c PRE : Trigger.new){
            preNew.add(PRE);

        }
        for(Public_Register_Employee__c publicReg : preNew){

            if(publicReg.Changed_Email__c != null){

                if(publicReg.Changed_email__c != publicReg.email__c){
                    for(Contact cont: [Select Id, Email from Contact WHERE Id =:publicReg.Id]){

                        cont.Email = publicReg.Changed_email__c;
                        cont.ESS_User__c =TRUE;
                        update cont;
                    }
                }
            }

            else if(publicReg.Changed_email__c != null){
                for(Contact cont: [Select Id, Email from Contact WHERE Id =:publicReg.Id]){                
                    cont.ESS_User__c = TRUE;
                    update cont;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: So many problems with your trigger, queries inside for loops, unnecessary collections etc. Seems you immediate issue is the fact that you are querying contacts matching the ID of a Public_Register_Employee__c so no results will be returned and thus nothing updated.

Comment: What you are trying to do with this trigger?

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger updateEmpEmail on Public_Register_Employee__c (after insert, after update) {  
    List <Public_Register_Employee__c> preNew = new List<Public_Register_Employee__c >();  
    List <Public_Register_Employee__c> preNewQry = new List<Public_Register_Employee__c >();  
    List<Contact> cont1 = new list<Contact>();
    cont1 =   [Select Id, Email from Contact WHERE Id =:trigger.newmap.keyset()];

        for(Public_Register_Employee__c publicReg : Trigger.new){

            if(publicReg.Changed_Email__c != null && publicReg.Changed_email__c != publicReg.email__c){

                    for(Contact cont:cont1){

                        cont.Email = publicReg.Changed_email__c;
                        cont.ESS_User__c =TRUE;

                    }


            }        update cont;

    }
```

Comment: This trigger is not bulkified. It will exceed the DML limits of 150 per execution context since you have `update cont` inside of a for loop. `cont` should be added to a list, then updated after the end of the final `for loop`. With a bulk insert or update operation, a fatal DML exception will occur with this trigger.

Answer (score 0):

For your business logic to work you need to query Contact matching values on your lookup field on Public_Register_Employee__c for contacts. I am assuming the lookup field on Public_Register_Employee__c for Contact is contact__c. The below code will not use any soql query.

```
trigger updateEmpEmail on Public_Register_Employee__c (after insert, after update) {  
List <Public_Register_Employee__c> preNew = new List<Public_Register_Employee__c >();  
List <Public_Register_Employee__c> preNewQry = new List<Public_Register_Employee__c >();  
List<Contact> contList = new list<Contact>();
Contact cont = new Contact();
    for(Public_Register_Employee__c publicReg : Trigger.new){

        if(publicReg.Changed_Email__c != null && publicReg.Changed_email__c != publicReg.email__c) {
             cont.id = publicReg.contact__c;
             cont.Email = publicReg.Changed_email__c;
             cont.ESS_User__c =TRUE;
             cont1.add(cont);
        }
    }
    update(cont1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger will update Parent record (Contact), if its email is not equal to child email (Public_Register_Employee__c)

```
trigger updateEmpEmail on Public_Register_Employee__c (after insert, after update) {

set<Id> contactIds = new set<Id>();
map<Id,Contact> contactMap;
map<Id,Contact> contactMapToUpdate = new map <Id,Contact>();

//collect related contact Ids
for(Public_Register_Employee__c PRE : Trigger.new) {
    if (PRE.contact__c != null)
        contactIds.add(PRE.contact__c);
}
//get map of contacts, **we are executing soql only once**
contactMap = new map <Id,Contact> ([select id, Email from Contact where id in :contactIds]);

for(Public_Register_Employee__c PRE : Trigger.new) {
    if ( PRE.Changed_Email__c != Null && contactMap.get(PRE.contact__c).email != PRE.Changed_Email__c ) {
        //Map will contain contact with email from latest employee
        contactMapToUpdate.put( PRE.contact__c, New Contact( id = PRE.contact__c, ESS_User__c = true, Email = PRE.Changed_Email__c ) );
    }
}
//**make update only once**
if (!contactMapToUpdate.isEmpty())
    update contactMapToUpdate.values();
}
```

Comment: If you describe in details what do you want to achieve in trigger, we could build better solution.

Comment: N.B. - the test for `isEmpty()` is unnecessary; if the `...values()` is empty, no DML statement is burned